# Drop down view on iPad showing black background

Tags: jquery, html, css, yii2

My website working very fine on all the browsers but when I tested it on an iPad the drop downs are showing with a black background. I have developed it in Yii2 Framework
[image]

I googled it but not found any solution. Can anyone tell me what the issue is and how to solve it?

Comment: I've never heard of that behavior before... It's a thing? I mean... did you found more people having the same issue? Can you try create another form just with a dropdown and check if the problem persists? If so, try deleting the temp files inside assets Folder and/or run a composer update (maybe you have something outdated)

Comment: Do you have a link for that?